# Setting the Back Button On the ToolBar, the margin appears at the top of the button, and the button moves down in Android 4.4

Tags: android, toolbar

Setting the Back Button On the ToolBar, the margin appears at the top of the button, and the button moves down in Android 4.4，in 5.X, 6.X, 7.X above shows the normal.

Here is the code:

**layout.xml**:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/my_collection_tool"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
                app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
                app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_arrow_back_white_24dp"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:titleTextColor="@color/white" />
```

**UI Effect:**
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my `layout.xml`, which is working on Android 4.4:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
```

Please try to use it. Maybe the problem is in your app theme or some additional toolbar settings.

Comment: Thank you!!Help me solve this problem, it seems that the theme is the reason.But my local theme is the same, do not know why。

Comment: The problem may be in your "Back" image. Your image size is 24dp, Toolbar size is 48dp. The icon margins should be 12dp to fully match the toolbar's hight. Maybe in Android 4.4. margins are 8dp (I've seen them such) and in newer versions they are greater.

Comment: So please try to increase image width and hight - to 32dp, for example. Change `android:width="24dp"` and `android:height="24dp"` to `32dp` in your `ic_arrow_back_white_24dp.xml`

Comment: The size of the icon looks like nothing, in accordance with the xml you provided, the problem has been solved and use the original icon. Theme seems to be the problem.Thanks

Comment: Great! Happy for you :)

Answer (score 0):

instead of adding `navigationIcon` in xml file. write below line after the.

```
setContentView(R.layout.....)
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

And to perform the action on the click of back arrow

```
 if (id == R.id.option1) {
     // it is id of any other menu available on the toolbar
} else {
    //write your code which should be execute on the click of back arrow

    onBackPressed(); // for navigating back
    finish();
}
```

if getActionbar doesn't supporting use getSupportActionbar instead.It will add the back navigation arrow in toolbar